# Angular2 - Cannot read property 'value' of undefined after navigate to login page

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2 and am making an API call to get back some JSON. The call works and I get a response.
But after navigate to login Page (when refresh-token) and when click on the submit button get :

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

working well after reload the page!.

Login.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
    import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
    import {HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
    import {Router} from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

      f: FormGroup;
      errorCredentials = false;

      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService,
                  private router: Router) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.f = this.formBuilder.group({
          email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
          password:[null, [Validators.required]]
        });
      }

      onSubmit(){

        this.authService.login(this.f.value).subscribe(
            (res) => {this.router.navigate(['admin']);},
            (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
             // console.log(errorResponse);
            if (errorResponse.status == 401) {
              this.errorCredentials = true;
            }
            }
        );
      }
```

Login.component.html

```
<div class="container app-login">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h1 class="text-center">
            <b>Angular</b> Laravel
            <br/>
            <small>Amr Ahmed</small>
          </h1>
          <br/>
          <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" *ngIf="errorCredentials">
            Email or password Invalid
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <form [formGroup]="f" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback" [ngClass]="{'has-success': f.controls['email'].valid,
                'has-error': f.controls['email'].invalid && (f.controls['email'].touched || f.controls['email'].dirty)}">
              <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="Email">
              <span *ngIf="f.controls['email'].valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span *ngIf="f.controls['email'].invalid && (f.controls['email'].touched || f.controls['email'].dirty)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="text-danger">E-mail Invalid.</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-success': f.controls['password'].valid,
                 'has-error': f.controls['password'].invalid && (f.controls['password'].touched || f.controls['password'].dirty)}">
              <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" id="InputPassword" placeholder="Password">
              <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f.controls['password'].invalid && (f.controls['password'].touched || f.controls['password'].dirty)">Password Invalid</span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="f.invalid" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

function go to login page

```
goToLogin(): void{

        const router = this.injector.get(Router);
        localStorage.clear();
        router.navigate(['auth/login']);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm. go to your service and inside the constructor write console.log("service instance created..."). and if it's being called more then once it means it's not singleton therefor the values won't be saved.  if that the issue let me know i will guide you to resolve it.

Comment: after navigate to login Page called for once.

Comment: and before navigation is it being called?

Comment: No,isn't being called.

Comment: so basically who is undefined? this.f.value? if yes try logging this.f and see if the form was initialized? your description is somewhat a mess but i hope i can help you.

Comment: thanks for your  time and efforts. yes,it's this.f undefined. when try logging with this.f ' is not assignable to parameter of login function.

Comment: try passing the form value from inside the template . (click)="onSumbit(f)"

Comment: I tried (click)="onSumbit(f)" and get the same error. the form still not initializing  after navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it work for me

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  f: FormGroup;
  email: FormControl;
  password: FormControl;
  errorCredentials = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.email = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.password = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

    this.f = new FormGroup({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    });
  }
```